# Decompose expression into specified form of partial fractions

Tags: expression-manipulation, partitions

In order to obtain the partial fractions of an expression, I used the function `Apart` to realize it. However the result is shown as Figure 1 which isn't what I want. The result I want is shown in Figure 2. There are three difference between them: 1)there are as few terms in the numerator as possible, 2)the partial fractions are as few as possible, 3)don't appear a negative sign before the first item in parentheses. How to do it? Thanks.

Code

```
Apart[-((1 + t)/(2 (-1 + t) (-1 + s t)))]
```

Figure 1

[image]

Figure 2

[image]

Comment: If `t` is the variable of interest, then Fig 2 is not a PFD for that expression. If `s` is the variable then the original expression is already in PFD form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = -((1 + t)/(2 (-1 + t) (-1 + s t)));
```

Multiply then divide by `(1 - s t)`, i.e., multiply by `1`

```
expr2 = (#/(1 - s t) & /@ ((1 - s t) expr // Simplify // Apart)) /. 
  a_/(t - 1) :> -a/(1 - t)

(* 1/(2 (1 - s t)) - 1/((1 - t) (1 - s t)) *)
```

Verifying the equivalence of the expressions

```
expr == expr2 // Simplify

(* True *)
```